# DXF Read Write dimensions

Tags: c#, autocad

I am developing a CAD application and have trouble in write Dimension (Aligned, linear and angular) to DXF (2000 LT) file and read the same data in C#? Thanks for your help

Comment: Reading and writing should be the easy part; DXF files are plain-text documents. What part (specifically) are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Brad I have reading and writing part of entities. I need this for dimensions like Aligned Linear and Angular. I want to write C# program to do this.

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem? The obvious way to figure out how any particular dataset is represented in DXF is to create the corresponding primitive manually in AutoCAD, export the resulting DWG file to DXF and look at the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [this library](http://netdxf.codeplex.com) ?

It comes with the C# source code and the dimensions are parameters.